# Can vibrations from stacking 2 External HDDs cause damage?

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive

Can vibration from 2 stacked external HDDs cause damage?
I have a stick-on HDD sleeve on my laptop with 2 pockets that's able to hold 2 HDDs at once. Would it cause any damage to have 2 HDDs, plugged in and reading/writing, stacked on top of each other in the sleeve?

[image]

My concern is that the 2 running HDDs stacked right on top of each other could amplify resonant vibrations that might cause performance issues or even damage over time. After all, I remember news about how the playing the song "Rhythm Nation" could crash old hard drives because the song happen to contain frequencies that matched hdd resonant frequency.

I know the other main issue is heat, and if I try this I'll definitely be monitoring the heat if I try this.

Comment: I severely doubt those drives vibrate enough through their plastic shell enough to cause a problem.  If you are really worried put a small piece of velcro between the drives to dampen any vibrations that does exist.

Comment: I can only give anecdotal advice but I am with @Ramhound on this.  I can't even begin to tell you the things I have put HDDs through over the last 30 years.  ONE TIME in 30 years have I had a problem and I dropped the drive from 4 feet up onto concrete.

Comment: As you state, *heat* could be an issue. If the drive shells have ventilation holes, make sure the sleeve does not block them. Also experiment with running them on the side, rather than flat, to get cooling air on *both* sides.

Answer (score 2):

It may not permanently damage a drive, but it could affect performance. ***Edit: It seems it has no or minimal affect on performance.***

I am only addressing the vibration question.

### Thought provoking

Even the tiniest of vibrations, for example caused by yelling at the drive may cause failed reads as my colleague demonstrated in this tiktok video:

https://www.tiktok.com/@forensicguy/video/7194473661561113862

After watching this (this isn't some prank video) I assumed vibrations caused by the one stacked drive might affect the performance of the other. After all, a failed read needs to be repeated to get a sector's data, which takes time.

You repeat the experiment using the same free software:

https://www.acelab.eu.com/downloads.php#Disk%20Analyser

**Screen caps from video:**

[image]

[image]

Based on this I did a quick preliminary test using the software from the TikTok video which you can find here: https://youtu.be/Zaj83ZYT3Pg, that does seem to suggest vibrations pass from one drive to the other and do have measurable effect.

To cause head movement I used my DiskTuna utility (https://www.disktuna.com/using-disktuna/) to cause head movement by indexing the file system on the other stacked drive.

screenshot:

[image]

Note that yellow and pink block indicate delays, not errors and that we're measuring micro seconds and so effect may be unnoticeable otherwise.

### Quick practical test using 2 stacked external drives

TL;DR: It appears @Ramhound (see comments) is correct.

- I don't see shocking effects during my small scale test while it seems to me the effect is not absent entirely. And although even if an effect is measurable in all likeliness it will not be noticeable during use.
- In fact, during one test while test subject is under stress from the tandem drive, it even performs marginally better.
- Test subject 2 performs marginally better unstacked under stress than in both stacked tests.

I stacked drives in a similar manner as seen in the question by @Dav.

**This test isn't scientific, it's limited and ad hoc.**

- Drive models used TOSHIBA TOSHIBA MQ04UBB400 (1) and MQ04UBD200 (2)
- On test subject I ran a *quick sequential test* using Victoria for Windows.
- To simulate a busy drive and associated vibrations I ran a *random seek test* on other stacked drive. This random seek test produced audible disk activity (head movement).

**Test sequence is**

1. Stacked, sequential scan on test subject 1
2. Stacked, sequential scan on test subject 1, random seek on drive 2 (vibrations source)
3. Stacked, sequential scan on test subject 2
4. Stacked, sequential scan on test subject 1, random seek on drive 2 (vibrations source)
5. NON-Stacked, sequential scan on test subject 1, random seek on drive 2 (vibrations source)

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Good idea. Yeah that figures. My line of thinking is that since both hard drives are 2.5in and spin at 5400 rpm that the vibrations from one drive could amplify vibration in the other, but I wasn't sure if this could be a valid concern or not

Comment: FWIW, I am planning on testing it tomorrow and will update my answer with my findings.

Comment: comparing bare exposed drive vs drive in portable enclosure which theoretically could have some anti-vibration features - though, I wouldn't risk it either :p

Comment: This answer assumes that mechanical drives are so sensitive that even the tiniest amount of vibrations cause issues. A drive mounted in a traditional desktop case would be exposed to more vibrations than a disk on a stationary desk. Modern mechanical HDDs, especially the one pictured in the author’s question, are no that sensitive.

Comment: @Ramhound: Hold your horses, I'll try.

Comment: @Ramhound: It appears you are correct!